# Add A CSS Class To A Menu Item When A Custom Taxonomy Term is Present On Single Post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, css, terms

I have a situation where if I'm on a single post page for a custom post type, if a custom taxonomy term is present I want to highlight the main nav menu related to that taxonomy term.

On archive pages this is fairly straight forward because I can use functions like `is_tax()` for a taxonomy and term, or `is_post_type_archive()` for a certain post type.

In the code below how would I add a CSS `.page-active` to a 'marketing' nav menu item when the custom term 'marketing' is present in the term list for the page. I am bringing the terms onto the page using `get_the_term_list()`

The code for the menu-item is:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-4"><a title="Marketing" class="td nav-link underline <?php if (is_tax('news_categories','marketing')){echo "page_active";};?>" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/news_categories/marketing'));?>">Marketing</a></li>
```

The code for showing the term on the custom post type single page is:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list ($post->ID, 'news_categories', ' ', ', ', ''); ?>
```

Any ideas how to approach this would be amazing.

Comment: You may need to create a custom nav walker. You can put the conditions inside the walker, so that if you're on a single Post (or Page, or CPT, or whatever content type the menu is on) you can check for taxonomies and add a class.

Comment: Hi @WebElaine what is a custom nav walker?

Comment: It's PHP that "walks" through the items in a WP nav menu and determines what HTML to output. There are lots of examples online - start with one and follow it exactly, and once you have that working, you can start tweaking until you get it the way you want your output, since the HTML possibilities are endless.

Comment: Hi @WebElaine I had a look at that actually and because I'm not using WP menu functions (the menu is hard-coded menu because of the very specific mobile design) I won't be able to go down that avenue. As far as I could see the walker functions only work with a WP registered menu.  I think I'm going have to look into doing it with regular expressions in JS.

Comment: That's correct, nav walkers only work with native nav menus. You could either convert it to a real nav menu (usually the ideal solution, since users can then edit as needed) and use a walker to adjust everything that needs to be set up so specifically; or else adjust the hard-coded menu. Either way it would be better to change the actual HTML output than to try to rearrange it with JS after the page loads.